# Python How To Import Files Like The Mac Does

Tags: macos, python-3.x, import, menu, pygame

I'm doing a note-taking software with PyGame and in the program I want to import some .png or .jpeg files to the background. It is easy to get an input and import an "x" file as "/Users/a/Desktop/Noting/a.jpg" But what I wanna do is to open a menu just like the Mac does.

[image]

How could I trigger that screen to be opened with Python and import files from there?

Answer (score 0):

`PyGame` is not `GUI Framework` and it doesn't have methods to open window and select file.

There are modules with some widgets for PyGame like [PGU](http://www.pygame.org/project-PGU+-+Phil's+pyGame+Utilities-108-.html) or [OcempGUI](http://www.pygame.org/project/125) and there can be simple window to select file. Maybe you should write it with real GUI framework like `tkinter`, `PyQt`, `wxPython`, etc.

---

BTW: They use own mainloop to control widgets so probably you will have to change own loop and use only methods from this GUI.